# Msys Git and Git on Ubuntu difference with the same repository

Tags: git, msysgit

I'm running Ubuntu on VM and MsysGit on Vista. I'm using Github as the git host and tracking the same repository from Msysgit too.

When I pull all the changes from Mysysgit and do the "git status", it lists the uncommitted changes. But when running "git status" from the Ubunutu, its all clean. No uncommitted changes.

Why is this happening in Msysgit.
Both version is 1.6

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue when I let MSysGit handle line endings. Currently I always install MsysGit with option not to convert line endings and commit them as they are.

Answer (score 1):

The source of this issue is more than likely a conflict with the way line-endings are being handled by msysgit. When you checkout commits on your Vista machine your Unix-style endings `LF` are being converted to Windows-style endings `CRLF`. This is being detected by Git as uncommitted changes.

I agree that its quite annoying.
Make sure that you select this option when installing msysgit.

[image: From the Msysgit install wizard.]

Alternatively you can alter your Git config to make an update to an existing install.
Set the value as `core.autocrlf=false`